# Question of the month badge

Tags: feature-request, badges

It would be nice to have a question of the month badge, possibly the question that received most upvotes in the previous month.

Similar badges may also exist for answers and different time periods.

Comment: Although it would obviously be wrong to do so, and will never happen I occasionally come across a question and think to myself that it should receive some sort of "worst question of the month" award.

Comment: Just a test to see if add comment still disappears. Will undo shortly.

Answer (score 12):

We already have "{nice|good|great|popular|notable|famous} question", and the blog question of the week (which often attracts a lot of viewers, earning at least one of the last three).

All I can see happening here is rewarding the "in" questions ("comic" etc) that are often controversial, and don't do anything to serve the *primary* site aim - answering peoples questions.

IMO, leave it alone.

Answer (score 3):

Even employee of the month scares me.
No, keep the amount of badges low. This would be too much inflation in the badge system.

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea in that anything that encourages "good" questions is a good thing.  A well thought out question that clearly defines the problem without ambiguity or requests for more information should be rewarded.

I don't think that basing it on the number of up-votes (or number of answers) is necessarily the best way to do it, though.  Quality should be rewarded, not popularity.  And the "fun" questions should be excluded.

Comment: Votes are indicative - but should not be determinative.  In particular, a question or answer in a less frequented tag (lower number of votes available) may be of as much merit as those in highly popular tags.  Of course, if you go by voting alone, then by definition the more popular tags are relevant and the minority interest ones are not.